# c# unittest change test outcome

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

for very specific reasons (explained below), I try to change the testoutcome after the execution of a unit test. 
I tried the following code:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        TestContext.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .First((fieldInfo) => fieldInfo.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("outcome"))
            .SetValue(TestContext, UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive);
    }
}
```

and other variants based on reflection. When I inspect the TestContext object after the execution of the TestCleanup method, the property CurrentTestOutcome is properly set to Inconclusive, but after that, the test still fails.

Do you please have any idea? I'm quite stuck here...

Thanks

**Reasons:**
These are not "real" unit tests, but more "end to end" tests. If some external dependency failed (I know how to detect it), and the test failed, I want to override its outcome to reduce the amount of false negatives.

Comment: Why don't you add a try/catch block to the test method and handle the problems there instead?

Comment: And if the external dependency fails but you don't care, it sounds like you should be handling that in your application code anyway. It looks like there is no way to do what you need to - I suspect the test engine stores the outcome separate from the `TestContext` before calling `Cleanup`

Comment: - LasseV.Karlsen: I can't easily because I have roughly 400 tests to change. In addition, I don't want the test code to become too verbose with try/catch, but instead having some elegant bindings doing that for the developers

- Rhumborl: I do care, and the test has to fail when the external dependency fails. But I want to distinguish the tests which are failing due to those dependencies, and those who fail due to the application code

Answer (score 1):

It may be late, but I managed to find a solution for this.

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common;
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace ServiceTests
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class Test
        {
            public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

            [TestCleanup()]
            public void MyTestCleanup()
            {
                if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
            {
                Type classType = this.GetType(TestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName);
                if (classType != null)
                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
                    MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod(TestContext.TestName);
                    try
                    {
                        method.Invoke(instance, null);

                        // if the above call does not throw exception it passes for sure, 
                        // so changing the previous status and message is needed to be done.
                        FieldInfo resultField = TestContext.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("m_currentResult")).First();

                        object currentTestResult = resultField.GetValue(TestContext);
                        FieldInfo outcomeProperty = currentTestResult.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("m_outcome")).First();
                        outcomeProperty.SetValue(currentTestResult, TestOutcome.Passed);

                        FieldInfo errorInfoProperty = currentTestResult.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("m_errorInfo")).First();

                        object errorInfoValue = errorInfoProperty.GetValue(currentTestResult);
                        FieldInfo messageProperty = errorInfoValue.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("m_message")).First();
                        messageProperty.SetValue(errorInfoValue, "Passed.");

                        FieldInfo stackTraceProperty = errorInfoValue.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("m_stackTrace")).First();
                        stackTraceProperty.SetValue(errorInfoValue, null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            private static int i = 0;
            [TestMethod]
            public void TMethod()
            {
                i++;
                if (i == 1)
                    Assert.Fail("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the field m_currentResult in TestContext. What version of visual Studio/mstest do you use?

Comment: VS 2015
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll - "14.0.25420.1"
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll - 14.0.23107.0", 

The MSTest.exe does not play any role here.

Comment: It throws on    line 30 (getField(m_currentResult)).

Comment: Can you check the fields' names from here TestContext.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic), probably in your dll the name is different ?

I'm attaching a screenshot of what I'm seeing from my perspective -
https://content.screencast.com/users/Vaptsarov/folders/Jing/media/9f9873f6-ec63-4833-b1d8-c5078b029350/2017-08-18_1330.png