# TFS 2017 Test plan: Set test cases as Not applicable or Blocked from trx result file

Tags: tfs, vstest.console.exe, test-plan

After execution automated tests in VStest task, vstest.exe generate trx result file. This trx contains only 3 types of outcome: Passed, Failed and Skipped. This types of outcome publish into TFS test plan.

Is there any possibility to add "Not applicable" or "Blocked" outcome into trx and update test cases in TFS test plan, based on this outcome?

I believe custom logger should be used, but what type of outcome can I use for "Not applicable" or "Blocked"?

```
    <Counters total="1" executed="0" passed="0" failed="0" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
```

There is 9 possible test outcomes for UnitTestOutcome
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.unittestoutcome?view=mstest-net-1.2.0
But actually vstest.exe generate and put into trx only 3 of this types.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your goal. An automated test can either run and fail, run and pass, or not run at all. The three statuses you're seeing encompass those possibilities. How can an automated test be "blocked" or "not applicable"?

Comment: I have test suite with test cases for whole feature. In some case I execute automated tests against instance with only few part of this feature. In this case for manual tester easy to set outcome as Not Acceptable for test cases that no  need to test. But automated test gets all of automated test cases and return failures for test cases that not applicable for instance, I update them manually after execution.
According this post
 is possible to change outcome for test
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728011/5265898
I tried it, MSTest generate TRX with multiple outcomes.

Comment: But Vstest return only 3 passed/failed/skipped

Comment: I understand that I can create separate test plan for separate instance and exclude part of test cases. But hard to maintenance this structure of test plans for multiple instances and thousands of test cases.

Comment: I think it's clear even from Publish test results task. In Result formats mapping, Outcome supports only this types passed/failed/skipped  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml